# Kernel panic - not syncing: Watchdog detected hard LOCKUP

Tags: linux-kernel, crash, kernel, crash-dumps, watchdog

Can someone help me why have i got this crash?

```
[2324956.184374] Kernel panic - not syncing: Watchdog detected hard LOCKUP on cpu 1
[2324956.184374] Pid: 0, comm: kworker/0:0 Tainted: P            3.1.10-gb20-default #1
[2324956.184374] Call Trace:
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff81003add>] dump_trace+0x98/0x223
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff813dc659>] dump_stack+0x69/0x6f
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff813def08>] panic+0xa4/0x1b4
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff81094b48>] watchdog_overflow_callback+0x79/0x9e
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff810b66b5>] __perf_event_overflow+0xf9/0x185
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff81010a2c>] intel_pmu_handle_irq+0x15d/0x1be
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff813f375b>] perf_event_nmi_handler+0x3e/0x87
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff813f4c0f>] notifier_call_chain+0x2e/0x5b
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff813f4c76>] __atomic_notifier_call_chain+0x3a/0x4d
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff813f4cc1>] notify_die+0x2d/0x32
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff813f2bbb>] default_do_nmi+0x29/0x1b5
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff813f2eb7>] do_nmi+0x47/0x6f
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff813f2a30>] nmi+0x20/0x30
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff8106b725>] arch_local_irq_save+0x1/0x17
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff813f1e9b>] _raw_spin_lock_irqsave+0xf/0x39
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff8105d9b7>] down_trylock+0xb/0x29
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff810409c2>] console_trylock+0xf/0x47
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff81040dc9>] console_unlock+0x100/0x129
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff8104120b>] vprintk+0x348/0x394
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff813df06b>] printk+0x53/0x58
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff81359902>] ip_handle_martian_source+0x6d/0xf6
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff8135b980>] ip_route_input_slow+0x45d/0x462
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff8135c02f>] ip_route_input_common+0x217/0x231
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff8137e995>] arp_process+0x181/0x4ac
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff81337bf5>] __netif_receive_skb+0x317/0x36b
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff81337b44>] __netif_receive_skb+0x266/0x36b
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff81339722>] netif_receive_skb+0x7e/0x84
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff8133979e>] napi_skb_finish+0x1c/0x31
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffffa02e1dee>] igb_clean_rx_irq+0x30d/0x39e [igb]
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffffa02e1ecd>] igb_poll+0x4e/0x74 [igb]
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff81339c88>] net_rx_action+0x65/0x178
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff81045c73>] __do_softirq+0xb2/0x19d
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff813f9aac>] call_softirq+0x1c/0x30
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff81003931>] do_softirq+0x3c/0x7b
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff81045f98>] irq_exit+0x3c/0xac
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff81003655>] do_IRQ+0x82/0x98
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff813f24ee>] common_interrupt+0x6e/0x6e
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff8123f91d>] intel_idle+0xdd/0x104
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff8130b76b>] cpuidle_idle_call+0xdf/0x181
[2324956.184374]  [<ffffffff81001201>] cpu_idle+0x56/0xa9
```

Comment: Debug the problem knowing only callstack? We are not magicians. In any case, we are not debugging service for 3d-party products.

Comment: Possible the culprit is the driver of network card, but it's just a guess.

Comment: Most likely what you see is hardlockup symptom - as you can see at the watchdog_overflow_callback implementation (and any other function from the stack) in the kernel, cpu is blocked whilst igb wanted to write some log (most likely because CONFIG_IP_ROUTE_VERBOSE was set). It does not mean that this particular call stack shows you a culprit but a symptom - you need to know what was happening in other kernel threads.

Comment: @RyszardGrzesica thanks but problem was occured because of longest ISR. console_unlock() function is calling from ISR, it is highly recommended of not using any blocking function from ISR. This hard lookup issue was occurred because heavy flood of martian source.